# How can I put this code in an external file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've made a little chat with nodeJS, now i want to put this part of code https://github.com/P-Pariston/nodeChat/blob/698ced0afc77e359a2bd32618baf66a873241816/app.js#L112-402 (in yellow) in an external file called commands.js.

Actually, i've tested this:

app.js

```
Command.prototype.parser = require('./commands.js');
```

commands.js

```
module.export = function (){...}
```

It doesn't work, i have:

"MongoClient is not defined".

All modules are not passed in commands.js as i can see (socket.io)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have mongo installed?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't include the context for MongoClient which has been set with a require at the top of the first set of code (outside the commands file)

MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,

Comment: I got ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Comment: same problem, you are defining things outside the scope (like socket) and then expecting them to be available in the file. the file acts as a separate piece, it doesn't know anything other than what you tell it. If you have an open socket, you could pass it in as a parameter function as one option.

Comment: How please, i'm not expert with node.js :\

Comment: modules.export = function(socket) {... 
then when calling the function Command.prototype.parser(socket) see 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming) for more detail.

Comment: It works, i passed the wrong var (io instead socket). Thank you very much.

Comment: glad you got it functioning.